# XPath expression to find all previous table rows from td element

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have an HTML page that contains a table with various rows

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>myTd</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

At the moment I have an XPath to find `td` that contains `myTd` text,

```
/table/tbody/tr/td/strong[text()="myTd"]
```

but now, I need to collect all previous `tr` from actual `td` (in this example, first four `tr` occurrences). I tried the following XPath, but it only returns the context row (fifth `tr`).

```
/table/tbody/tr/td/strong[text()="myTd"]/ancestor::tr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/table/tbody/tr[td/strong/text()='myTd']/preceding-sibling::tr/td
```

It selects the four previous `td` elements.

*Please note that I changed "MyTd" to "myTd", because there has been a mismatch between your XML and your XPath expressions. Now the question's XML, its XPath expressions and the answer do refer to the same elements.*

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
/table/tbody/tr[td="myTd"]/preceding-sibling:tr
```

will select all preceding sibling `tr` elements before the `tr` element that has a `td` whose string value is `"myTd"`, regardless of any `strong` or other wrapping markup.